# how to clear a value from a php variable and reuse the variable

Tags: php, phpmailer, sendmail

this code send emails to all employees from mail table where the cols are Id, Name, Email. Now for example,
if there are 3 employees, then the first employee gets all the 3 payslips as attachment, the 2 employee gets the 2nd and 3rd payslip and the 3rd employee gets the 3rd payslip only. I think that the stored email values are creating the problem and so I want to clear the data stored in a $sendto, $pdf and $filename variable. I have tried apc_delete(), unset(), and also $var = "" but none is working.

this is the code :

```
    <?php
    //require 'mailerClass/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    require_once '../connect.php';
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    //Load composer's autoloader
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
    $cin =1;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mail";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    try {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    //
        $sendto = $row['Email'];
        //attachment pdf files path array
        $path = "C:/Reports/";
        $file = $row['Name'];
        $extension = ".pdf";
        $filename = $file.$extension;
        $pdf = $path. $file. $extension ;



        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        //$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'username@yahoo.com';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = '@password';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 465;      //587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('mediakraft64@yahoo.com');
        $mail->addAddress($sendto);     // Add a recipient

        $mail->addReplyTo('mediakraft64@yahoo.com');
        $mail->addCC('mediakraft64@yahoo.com');
        //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Payslip';
        $mail->Body    = 'Payslip from Mediakraft Check file attachment';
        $mail->AltBody = 'Payslip from Mediakraft Check file attachment';

    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );



        $mail->addAttachment($pdf, $filename);      //= $_POST['mypdf'];

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';

    //unset($sendto);
    $sendto = " ";
    $pdf = " ";
    $mail->clearAttachments();
    sleep(5);

    } //end while

    echo"<script>alert('Email Sent... Successfully'); document.close();</script>";

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    ?>
```

any help ??

Thanks

Comment: This is nothing to do with unsetting a variable, it's because every iteration of the loop just adds another recipient to the same `$mail` instance. You need to clear the recipients after sending each email, the same way you clear the attachments.

Comment: is it $mail->clearaddAddress();

Comment: Thanks @iainn , it is SOLVED.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to reuse the variable, just reassign a new value to it:

```
$a = 1;
$a = "a string";
$a = new MyClass();
```

The old value is automatically deleted (if needed) by PHP's engine. You don't have to worry about that.

Comment: reusing part is secondary, primary is to clear the data stored in the variable

Answer (score -1):

`unset` will remove the variable and the contents. Referencing `$a` after calling `unset($a)` will throw an error. Also, you have to think about the scope of the variable you are unsetting, and if it was passed by reference or by copy inside a function.

To remove only the contents, there is no specific built-in PHP instruction. Just assign `null` or `false` to it if you have to signal that the variable does not hold valid data anymore or to free the memory it currently uses.

There is not such thing as "clearing a variable". You can use `empty()` to see if *PHP considers* that a variable is empty.

Comment: the problem is .. a variable takes a email id from sql table and sends a mail and then on next iteration of the while loop , it keeps the 1st email id and also takes the 2nd email id and sends the next mail to both the ids .. :(